# REST request for creating list, 404

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest

When I send the create list request

`https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists` as POST request, and set header as:

```
Authorization:Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Accept:application/json; odata=verbose 
body: 
{
       "metadata": {"type":"SP.List"},
       "AllowContentTypes": "true",
       "BaseTemplate":"100",
       "ContentTypesEnabled":"true",
       "Description":"My list description",
       "Title": "TESTTEST"
 }
```

It returns:

```
{
    "text": "404 FILE NOT FOUND"
}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: for one its: ``__metadata`` and not ``metadata``

Comment: Maybe @Atish's blog post could help... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API or here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_List

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set additional headers like request digest. You can use the below code to create list using REST(just make sure you have a jquery reference):

```
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists";

$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: "POST",
    data:JSON.stringify(
    {'__metadata': 
        { 'type': 'SP.List' 
        }, 
    'AllowContentTypes': true,
    'BaseTemplate': 100, 
    'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 
    'Description': 'My list description', 
    'Title': 'TESTTEST' }),
    headers: {
    "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest":$("#_REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},       
success: onSuccess,       
error: onError   
});

function onSuccess(data) {

console.log(data+ ' List Created');
}

function onError(error) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}

});
```